# "Visual Studio 2022: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 91"

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, visual-studio-2022

Does anyone know how to fix the below error? My browser version is currently on: Version 120.0.6099.217. I don't want to downgrade as I will lose all my settings.

Message:

> System.InvalidOperationException : session not created: This version
> of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 91 Current browser
> version is 120.0.6099.217 with binary path C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe (SessionNotCreated)

Running my tests in VS 2022. I tried updating the Chrome Driver, however the latest from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads, but only found ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90. "

Comment: there is clearly red text saying that from 115 you must switch to json endpoints. Going to the dashboard. clicking 120 stable gives use all of the links for different OS. for windows64bit newest chromedriver link is ```chrome win64 https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/120.0.6099.109/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip```